# Join second table based on third table with conditions

Tags: mysql, join, orm

I"m using Doctrine for a website that has 3 tables to connect together. In simplest terms, they look like this

```
Contractor
- id
- name

ContractorJob
- id
- contractor_id
- job_id
- status

Job
- id
- start_date
- end_date
```

I want to join Jobs to Contractors based on a date range, but you can see that the only way to do that is through the ContractorJob table. It means that a simple inner join between Contractor and ContractorJob is essentially random, and therefore the subsequent join between ContractorJob and Job is mostly useless.

How can I join Contractor to Job using start_date and end_date as conditions?

Pseudo query is as follows

```
select from contractor c
left join ContractorJob cj on cj.contractor_id = c.id
left join job j with j.contractor_job = cj.id and j.start_date < :start_date and j.end_date > :end_date
where j.id is null
```

(find all contractors who do not have a job in the given date range)

*note: Doctrine is a web framework DB manager that handles low level query processing so that applications can use more high-level functions. It allows you to say `query.innerJoin('a.second_table', 'b')` and have the correct join made

Comment: `with`? The syntax needs `on`:  `a join b on <condition>`

Comment: Doctrine uses WITH when doing leftJoins, but you're right otherwise

Comment: What is Doctrine? You have tagged the question with MySQL, not Doctrine.

Comment: My mistake, there is no Doctrine tag. It's a web framework that handles queries directly so you can build requests with a cleaner interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with the query

- The `select` list is missing.
- The join syntax needs `ON`, not `WITH`:  `a JOIN b ON <some condition>`
- There is a missing `on` condition (what you correctly identified as arbitrary/random join between `Contractor` and `ContractorJob`).
- There are column names mismatches between the code and the design: (`Job.contractor_job` vs. `Job.id`). Which is the correct one?

How to write it with `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`. The parentheses are redundant, placed only for making the joins more clear:

```
select 
    c.*
from 
        Contractor as c
    left join
        ( 
            ContractorJob as cj
        inner join 
            Job as j 
        on  
                j.id = cj.job_id 
            and j.start_date < :start_date 
            and j.end_date > :end_date
        )
    on 
        c.id = cj.contractor_id
where 
    cj.contractor_id is null ;
```

How to write it with `NOT EXISTS` which I find easier to grasp:

```
select c.*
from Contractor as c
where not exists
    ( select * 
      from ContractorJob as cj
        inner join Job as j 
        on  j.id = cj.job_id 
      where j.start_date < :start_date 
        and j.end_date > :end_date
        and c.id = cj.contractor_id
    ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion about not exists and subqueries pointed me in the right direction.